# Jinja Creating /n (next line) functionality

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm looking for a way to make a marco that results in `/n`

For example,

```
something
{/n_macro}
something
```

Expected outcome,

```
something

something
```

Comment: What about <br>?

Answer (score 0):

Flask has [method(clickable)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Markup) which can return "generated" html.

In your python file you can use it:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    smth = Markup("<br>")
    return render_template("index.html", tag=smth)
```

And then in templates folder, in html file you can call variable by Jinja

```
Text{{ tag }}Text
```

Output of this code will be

```
Test
Test
```

Comment: Yes, you're 100%. I was trying to think of purely jinja functionality but seems like there would need to be some scripting process